# Gear s3 Native Sample "UI -> (circle)Sensors" is White Screen

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, samsung-galaxy-gear, wearables

I developed using Gear S3.

I have received the sensor values of the gear S3. So I run Sensors sample, whitch shows the sensor value and information of sensors in the Native.

The virtual machine has confirmed that it works smoothly.

But Running on Gear S3 only prints the White Screen.

Can I tell you what the problem is?

Tizen Studio version 1.2, Gear S3 Tizen version 2.3.2.4, Sample : Native -> UI -> (Circle)Sensors, Sample tizen version 2.3.1, virtual machine's version 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 3.0 were confirmed well

---

i just see https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors?langredirect=1
and i solved.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? What's the status right now?

Comment: It was resolved in another way. From the beginning, I made a new start. So now It worked well.

Comment: If it's possible then you may share your findings here so that it can help other developers.

Comment: See here https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors?langredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the sensor sample's UI module or target device UI framework. Fortunately, you can use important information about sensors. I think there is no problem in the code of sample application.

You can find it in `data.c` file.

I think you will need to create your own code based on how to use the sensor through the sample.

Below is the tizen official site that shows how to use the sensor.
https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors

Good luck. :)

Comment: Thx. It was resolved in another way. From the beginning, I made a new start. So now It worked well